# How to setup 64-bit ODBC data source in UiPath?

Tags: odbc, 64-bit, datasource, uipath

I am trying to set up a 64-bit ODBC data source connection in UiPath, but it's not visible and only showing 32-bit data sources.

Is it because UiPath is a 32-bit software? Please suggest an alternate workaround.

[image: 32-bit data source is visible in uipath]

Answer (score 1):

A 32-bit application can only load 32-bit ODBC drivers.

Your options are to --

- find a 64-bit version of your "UiPath" application
- find a 32-bit version of the 64-bit "Oracle in XE" driver
- find a 32-bit ODBC Driver for 64-bit ODBC Data Sources (such as [this, from my employer](https://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/), available for [immediate download with free two-week trial license](https://shop.openlinksw.com/license_generator/uda/?releaseVersionSelection=7.x&licenseFamilySelection=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fontology%2Fsoftware%23ODBCBridge&licenseEngineSelection=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fontology%2Fsoftware%23odbc&driverEditionSelection=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.openlinksw.com%2Foplweb%2Fproduct_format%2Fmt%23this&productSelection=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.openlinksw.com%2Foplweb%2Fproduct%2Fodbc-odbc-mt%23this&opsysFamilySelection=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fontology%2Fsoftware%23Windows&opSystemSelection=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.openlinksw.com%2Foplweb%2Fopsys%2Fx86_64-generic-win-64%23this&clientOSFamilySelection=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fontology%2Fsoftware%23Windows&clientOSSelection=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.openlinksw.com%2Foplweb%2Fopsys%2Fi686-generic-win-32%23this))

Answer (score 0):

Connect activity in UiPath drops down only 32bit data sources. I solved this using following method.

- Go to Oracle official website and download Oracle Instant Client 32
  bit. (Link[1](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html))
- Download Basic Package (in Base section), SDK Package and ODBC
  Package (in Develpoment and Runtime section).
- Extract them in a directory.
- There will be folder created similar to instantclient_19_3. Open this
  folder and run **odbc_install.exe** (Might prompt for administrator
  privilegs)
- Sometimes there might be messages stating that "This program is not
  installed correctly". Ignore this message.

That's all. Create a data source using ODBC Data Source Administrator Application(32 bit) in Windows machine.There you will be able to create an Oracle data source using Oracle instantclient_19_3 driver.

[Refer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PZbu.png)

After successful creation of this data source, now you will be able to see your data source from UiPath Connect activity.