# How to connect UiPath to Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, uipath, badimageformatexception

I am getting this error while connecting UiPath to Oracle DB:
`BadImageFormatException`. This occurs when running in 64-bit mode with the 32-bit Oracle client components installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup 64-bit ODBC data source in UiPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181871/how-to-setup-64-bit-odbc-data-source-in-uipath)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message.

Your Oracle DB client that is being ran by UiPath is in its 32-bits version, but your Oracle DB server is in 64 bits.

Make sure that your Oracle DB client and server are either both 32 bits or both 64 bits.

Useful link: [32bit vs 64bit programs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/15056/windows-7-32-64-bit-faq)